# How to trigger gh-pages branch changes via another action

Tags: github-actions

I got this action which publishes to gh-pages successfully :

```
name: Deployment
on:
    push:
        branches:
            - master
jobs:
    deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        strategy:
            matrix:
                node-version: [12.x]
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v1
            - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
              uses: actions/setup-node@v1
              with:
                  node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
            - name: Install Packages
              run: npm install
            - name: Build page
              run: npm run build
            - name: Deploy to gh-pages
              uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
              with:
                  deploy_key: ${{ secrets.ACTIONS_DEPLOY_KEY }}
                  publish_dir: ./build
```

I added second action

```
name: S3Publish
on:
    push:
        branches:
            - gh-pages
```

... but it never triggers [image]

Comment: Did you add any job in the second action?

Answer (score 0):

We can also put `.github` directory including your second workflow to the `gh-pages` branch.

```yaml
- name: Deploy
  uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
  with:
    deploy_key: ${{ secrets.ACTIONS_DEPLOY_KEY }} # Recommended
    personal_token: ${{ secrets.PERSONAL_TOKEN }} # An alternative
    # github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}   # Dot not use this token for this case.
    exclude_assets: ''
```

Set `exclude_assets` to empty for including the `.github` directory to deployment assets.

For more details, see the latest README: [How to trigger gh-pages branch changes via another action - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62486239/how-to-trigger-gh-pages-branch-changes-via-another-action)